# AngularJS inside XSLT : The Prefix 'true' is not declared

Tags: angularjs, xslt

I am having a button with ng-repeat , inside which based on default product I am applying an active class.

```
                <button type="button" ng-model="selectedProductGroup" ng-repeat="item in pgroup |unique: 'Product' track by $index" ng-click='pgf(item)' 
                ng-class="{true:'active', false:''}[item.Product==defaultProduct]"
                >{{item.Product}}</button>
```

This is working fine in normal environment, but inside XSLT we are getting error like below:

[XPathParserException: The prefix 'true' is not declared. expression = 'true:'active', false:''' Remaining tokens are: () (E:\OpenText\LES1\support\powertools\views\44241142, line 173, column 22)]

Answer (score 0):

Inside of literal result attributes you will have to double the curly braces e.g. `ng-class="{{true:'active' false:''}}..."` as XSLT otherwise interprets the contents inside of curly braces as XPath expressions in so called [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).